# How to apply filters on getting filtered emails from Outlook using Microsoft Graph v1.0

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get a filtered emails list by users. They must be able to choose between several options, including "from" and/or "toRecipients" emails. When I submit a query with both emailAddress filter, I get the following error:

RequestBroker--ParseUri: The parent value for a property access of a property 'emailAddress' is not a single value. Property access can only be applied to a single value.

My code (angular, by the way) is as follow:

```
  try {    
    var fecha1 = new Date(req.body.fecha1);        
    var fecha2 = new Date(req.body.fecha2);        
    var fecha1 = fecha1.getFullYear() + "-" + fecha1.getMonth() + "-" + fecha1.getDate();
    var fecha2 = fecha2.getFullYear() + "-" + fecha2.getMonth() + "-" + fecha2.getDate();                

    var tipoFecha = (req.body.i_o == 1) ? "receivedDateTime" : "sentDateTime";

    var filtro = "startswith(subject, \'" + req.body.subject + "\') and " +
    "startswith(from/emailAddress/name,\'" + req.body.from + "\') or " + 
    "startswith(toRecipients/emailAddress/name,\'" + req.body.to + "\') and " + 
    tipoFecha + " ge " + fecha1 + " and " + 
    tipoFecha + " lt " + fecha2;

    let result = await client
    .api("/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?filter=" + filtro)
    .select('id,subject,from,toRecipients,ccRecipients,bccRecipients,body,sentDateTime,receivedDateTime')
    .get();

    var emails = {
      estado: 1,
      descripcion: "ok",
      correos: result.value
    };

    res.json(emails);

 }
```

My question is, there is any other way to filter by both email address?